# Java ForkJoin Multi-threaded is slower than single thread

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join

I was trying out the Java ForkJoin framework and wrote a simple test program that sets the pixels of an image to random colors. E.g. it generates pseudo-noise.

But while testing performance I found that it's actually faster to run single threaded than to run it with multiple threads. I make it run single threaded by passing a high threshold.

This is the class worker class:

```
public class Noise extends RecursiveAction {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int xMin;
    private int yMin;
    private int xMax;
    private int yMax;
    private int threshold = 2000000; // max pixels per thread

    public Noise(BufferedImage image, int xMin, int yMin, int xMax, int yMax, int threshold) {
        this.image = image;
        this.xMin = xMin;
        this.yMin = yMin;
        this.xMax = xMax;
        this.yMax = yMax;
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }

    public Noise(BufferedImage image, int xMin, int yMin, int xMax, int yMax) {
        this.image = image;
        this.xMin = xMin;
        this.yMin = yMin;
        this.xMax = xMax;
        this.yMax = yMax;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        int ppt = (xMax - xMin) * (yMax - yMin); // pixels pet thread
        if(ppt > threshold) {
            // split
            int verdeling = ((xMax - xMin) / 2) + xMin;
            invokeAll(new Noise(image, xMin, yMin, verdeling, yMax),
                    new Noise(image, verdeling+1, yMin, xMax, yMax));
        }
        else {
            // execute!
            computeDirectly(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax);
        }
    }

    private void computeDirectly(int xMin, int yMin, int xMax, int yMax) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
            for (int y = yMin; y < yMax; y++) {
                //image.setPaint(new Color(generator.nextInt()));
                int rgb = generator.nextInt();
                int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                int blue = rgb & 0xFF;

                red = (int) Math.round((Math.log(255L) / Math.log((double) red)) * 255);
                green = (int) Math.round((Math.log(255L) / Math.log((double) green)) * 255);
                blue = (int) Math.round((Math.log(255L) / Math.log((double) blue)) * 255);

                int rgbSat = red;
                rgbSat = (rgbSat << 8) + green;
                rgbSat = (rgbSat << 8) + blue;

                image.setRGB(x, y, rgbSat);
            }

        }
        Graphics2D g2D = image.createGraphics();
        g2D.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2D.drawRect(xMin, yMin, xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin);
    }
}
```

When generating a 6000 * 6000 image the results are:
Single thread: 9.4sec @ 25% CPU load
Multi thread: 16.5sec @ 80%-90% CPU load
(Core2quad Q9450)

Why is the multi-threaded version slower?
How do I fix this?

Comment: have you tried splitting by y instead of x? I think BufferedImage is likely to be stored row-major in memory, and this might make a difference.

Comment: A bigger problem could be that BufferedImage and Graphics objects are not thread safe. You might want to generate the noise in arrays, and the creating a BufferedImage at the end directly from the data (which will also be faster than using setRGB).

Comment: As to your first comment: I've switched to splitting by Y, but it makes no difference.

Comment: if you can optimise the code. e.g. remove log. you might get more of a speed improvement than using multiple threads will you

Comment: for the single threaded performance you compare without fork/join as it could be faster as it would be simpler.

Comment: I suspect the single threaded version is using all your cache and possibly you CPU to main memory bus. using multiple threads might not help.

Comment: @Peter: I use The log methods to saturate the colors. 
Your memory bus comment sounds very plausible, it could also explain why the CPU load is never above 80%-90%, even with a lot of threads running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, F/J is a niche product. If you don't have a HUGE array and process it as a DAG then you're using the wrong product. Sure, F/J can make use of multiple processors, but so can just using a simple multi-threaded approach without all the overhead of F/J.

Try using four threads and just give each a quarter of the work directly.

This is the way F/J was meant to be used:

```
Sum left  = new Sum(array, low, mid);
Sum right = new Sum(array, mid, high);
left.fork();
long rightAns = right.compute();
long leftAns   = left.join();
return leftAns + rightAns;
```

When you don't walk down the leaves of a structured tree, then all bets are off.

Comment: You're probably right, but the point of this program was to test the workings of ForkJoin (as stated). So that stil leaves me wondering why it's happening this way?

Comment: How about replacing the inokeAll() with fork(), join() the way this recursively decomposing framework was designed to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you found was unrelated to your code directly, the culprit was the [BufferedImage#setRGB()](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/6f1875b6f29f/src/share/classes/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.java#l1015) method:

```
public synchronized void setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {...}
```

So the test case was so slow because of contention on this method.

As a workaround in the JDK 8 you could use a similar method:

```
public void setRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h,
                   int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize) {...}
```

Since JDK 10 this is not a problem anymore, the synchronized keyword was removed: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8183576

Here is my execution time:

|  | JDK 8 | JDK 17 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| single-thread | 3 sec | 3 sec |
| multi-thread | 7 sec | 1 sec |

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use ThreadLocalRandom instead of Random.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threadlocalrandom.html

Answer (score 0):

Because of the overhead? Forking and Joining takes time as well.. maybe you need a larger test set? Or do more work in the threads themselves?

Comment: Execution time is ~16sec on a Quad core, so 64sec coretime. With a 2M limit on a 6000*6000 image, so that yields 32 threads, that's about 2sec execution time per thread. So the overhead of creating threads should be fairly low I think?
On the other hand, single threaded execution takes 9,5sec of coretime. But where do those 55sec coretime overhead go?